# Coinbase callback returning a '422 Unprocessable Entity' after POST - Rails 4

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-4, callback

I'm trying to set up methods to handle callbacks from Coinbase for my app. When I send test callbacks via a POST, my "Server responded with: 422 Unprocessable Entity".

The callback/POST is just sending a simple JSON and expecting a status 200 back.  I've tried to make things uber simple first just for testing.  This is what I have in my controller:

```
def callbacks
   render json: {status: "OK"}
end
```

But even with that, I'm getting this in my server console logs:

```
2014-10-10T16:31:30.318374+00:00 app[web.1]: Started POST "/contribute/callbacks for 173.245.56.73 at 2014-10-10 09:31:30 -0700
2014-10-10T16:31:30.323217+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"order"=>{"id"=>nil, "created_at"=>nil, "status"=>"completed", "event"=>nil, "total_btc"=>{"cents"=>100000000, "currency_iso"=>"BTC"}, "total_native"=>{"cents"=>35925, "currency_iso"=>"USD"}, "total_payout"=>{"cents"=>35925, "currency_iso"=>"USD"}, "custom"=>"123456789", "id"=>nil}, "transaction"=>{"id"=>"54380", "hash"=>"4a5e1b", "confirmations"=>0}}}}
2014-10-10T16:31:30.324629+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms
2014-10-10T16:31:30.323041+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PaymentsController#callbacks as JSON
2014-10-10T16:31:30.324325+00:00 app[web.1]: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
```

I would really appreciate any help. I have also tried variations of render. Dont know what to do next to troubleshoot.

Comment: Try posting the rest of your controller

Comment: That's all I have for my controller method.  I would like a status 200 before adding more.